# Android display value from JSON Object

Tags: java, android, json

I have json that looks likes this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1428783374000,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-04-04&endtime=2015-04-05","title":"USGS Earthquakes","status":200,"api":"1.0.17","count":328},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":1.3,"place":"8km SSE of Talmage, California","time":1428191575500,"updated":1428359465102,"tz":-420,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72426686","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=nc72426686&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":26,"net":"nc","code":"72426686","ids":",nc72426686,","sources":",nc,","types":",cap,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,tectonic-summary,","nst":12,"dmin":0.08508,"rms":0.06,"gap":154,"magType":"md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 1.3 - 8km SSE of Talmage, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-123.1233333,39.0688333,7.27]},"id":"nc72426686"},
```

My Main Activity code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static final String LOG_TAG ="JSON STRING";
TextView httpData;
HttpClient client;
JSONObject json;


final static String URL = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-04-04&endtime=2015-04-05";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    httpData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHttp);
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();

    new Read().execute("features");

}

public JSONObject lastEvent(String event) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if ( status == 200 ) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        JSONArray timeline = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONObject last = timeline.getJSONObject(0);

        return last;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}


public class Read extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            json = lastEvent("title");
            return json.getString(params[0]);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result ) {
       httpData.setText(result);
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

My activity_main.xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView android:text="Loading Data" android:id="@+id/tvHttp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

I am trying to get the value of 'title' from the first element of the JSONArray, but instead I just get a blank Text View screen. I am somewhat new to Java and Android in general, so if a different format (such as XML) is easier for me to work with, I can try that too. Any insight or hints is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either I misunderstood it, or I'm unsure why this doesn't throw errors. If the above JSON Format is everything you've got, you'll need to create a `JSONObject` and then you can use `getString("title")`. You however create a `JSONArray`.

Comment: You're saying I should not create the JSONArray and just get it straight from the JSONObject?

Comment: Okay, I just reread you question. Are you trying to get the title from the outer most object? Or are you trying to get a field of the `features` array?

Comment: A field from the features array- the 'title' field for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, assuming we have the JSON you posted

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1428783374000,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2015-04-04&endtime=2015-04-05","title":"USGS Earthquakes","status":200,"api":"1.0.17","count":328},"features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"mag":1.3,"place":"8km SSE of Talmage, California","time":1428191575500,"updated":1428359465102,"tz":-420,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/nc72426686","detail":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=nc72426686&format=geojson","felt":null,"cdi":null,"mmi":null,"alert":null,"status":"reviewed","tsunami":0,"sig":26,"net":"nc","code":"72426686","ids":",nc72426686,","sources":",nc,","types":",cap,general-link,geoserve,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,scitech-link,tectonic-summary,","nst":12,"dmin":0.08508,"rms":0.06,"gap":154,"magType":"md","type":"earthquake","title":"M 1.3 - 8km SSE of Talmage, California"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-123.1233333,39.0688333,7.27]},"id":"nc72426686"},
```

It's an `object`. We want to get into the array in key `features`, and we want the title key in the first element (which is an object) of that array.

---

Looking at your `lastEvent` function. You pass a String called `event`. But that is never used.

```
public String lastEvent(String event) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, JSONException {
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL);

    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);

    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if ( status == 200 ) {
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        // data now contains the json object I posted above
        // So we fetch it
        JSONObject timeline = new JSONObject(data);
        // We want the features array
        JSONArray features = timeline.getJSONArray("features");
        // The first element
        JSONObject first = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
        // The titles attribute. I assume lastEvent("titles")
        // is the way you call this function
        String last = first.getString(event);

        return last;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note I changed the return type of lastEvent, because we are getting a String from the object. The first parameter `event` now is for the field we want to get, I think that was your intention, because you call it like that in the AsyncTask.

---

Also, check your Logcat! A `JSONException` might be thrown, that you catch and print its message and return null. Returning null, and later calling `httpData.setText(null)` would result in an empty `TextView`

---

Edit: Also your `doInBackground` function doesn't need to call `getString()` anymore on the return value of `lastEvent`.
I don't know how generic your  `AsyncTask` needs to be. But the code I wrote might help you to get where you want to be.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. I am still not quite there though. Do I need to modify my `AsyncTask` to return a String instead of JSONObject?

Comment: @perlsufi yes, because my changes lead to directly getting the content of `title`, which is a String.